# Match listbox First column number to sheet first column number and copy paste number on existing sheet adjacent matching number vba excel

Tags: vba

I have a multicolumn list box and there are many single or duplicate number in first column.
When Click command button then listbox first columns numbers will be match with sheet1
column(B) numbers. Sheet1 column(B) numbers are unique.
Copy sheet1 column(E) data and paste column(C) only matching unique numbers.

Please help me, i am worry about it.

My code is :

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim x As Long

Dim fCell As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

With ws

Set fCell = .Range("A:A").Find(Me.listbox1.value, , xlValues, xlWhole)

'If record doesn't match, do nothing
If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

x = fCell.Row

p = .Cells(i, 5).Value

.cells(i, 3).value=p

End With

End Sub
```

Here is my sample of Listbox1...
[Listbox1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3iVU.png)

My sheet1:
[Sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FO5OL.png)

Now when listbox1 First Column (Code) will match with Sheet(Sheet1) Column:B (Code) then
Sheet1 Column:E (H-Qty) copy and paste in Column:C (G-Qty).
Copy and Paste will be only by match (listbox1 & sheet1 => code)
Here is the picture what i want:
[Change Sheet1 After Matching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i0Nj.png)

Comment: Please, show us what you tried by your own.

Comment: Your question is not so clear for me, at least.. So, what are you trying to do? Clicking the button, to treat a specific selected item from the list box in order to find each first occurrence in column "B:B" and copy range "E" of the found cell row in "C"? If yes, try replacing `i` (from `.Cells(i,...` with `x`. If it still does not work, place the next code line to check if the `Find` function returns a range: `Debug.Print fCell.Address: Stop`. Insert this line immediately after `If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub`. Does your code reach this line?

Comment: I give sample (1) listbox1 (2) sheet1 (3) changing sheet1

Comment: Then, please test the code I posted and send some feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next adapted code:

```
Private Sub commandbutton1_Click()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, x As Long, fCell As Range

 Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
 If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub  'when nothing selected
 ListBox1.BoundColumn = 1                     'column where from to return the value

 With ws
    Set fCell = .Range("A:A").Find(Me.ListBox1.value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    'If record doesn't match:
    If fCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        x = fCell.row
         .cells(x, 3).value = .cells(x, 5).value
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is finely work. But the listbox1 never selected. And no need Debug.Print "No match for" Because all the time it will be match. Kindly help me your next feedback. Thanks

Comment: @Shahin Alam I am afraid I cannot get you... If anything is selected in the list box, `Me.ListBox1.value` will not return the necessary value. Are you referring to the line `If Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1 Then Exit Sub`? Then, if you are sure that will always be a match, you can also skip all line starting with `If fCell Is Nothing...`. Anyhow, I will remove the `Debug.Print` part. It was there only for cases when something unexpected happened, to easily debug it... Removed the required code line.

Comment: That's why I'm worried. Thanks for your feedback. If you have any new information without above discussion, Kindly share me.

Comment: @Shahin Alam I must confess I do not understand what you want saying, sorry... I would also like to inform you that we here, when somebody answer our question, tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the code works and answered the question. So, do you consider that the above code did not answer your question? If yes, which part of your question was not answered?